# How do biologists infect cells with viruses within a lab setting?

Tags: cell-biology, virology, coronavirus

I'm writing an experimental proposal as my final paper for my single molecule biophysics class. Part of the procedure I wrote involves intentionally infecting a culture of HeLa cells with SARS-CoV-2 in order to perform a series of tests on it. Are there any readings or articles that you guys can point me to which detail how biologists intentionally infect cells with viruses within a lab setting?

Comment: A good strategy when writing a proposal like this is to read the methods sections of papers in the literature. You can probably use searches that include terms like "in vitro" and members of the class of viruses you are interested in studying - both the original SARS virus and SARS-CoV-2 would be good places to start, MERS would also be reasonable. You might not find your answer in the first paper you look at, so expect to look at a few, and expect that you might need to go to a source that is cited by one of the papers you initially read. Note that your instructor likely wants you do to this.

Comment: I'm closing this question as Homework because I think getting a thorough answer here would interfere with the purpose of the assignment you were given. I'll let @MikeyC's answer remain because it is helpful but doesn't go so far as to complete your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to consider whether HeLa cells are the optimal cell line for acheiving your objectives. [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340822055_Comparative_tropism_replication_kinetics_and_cell_damage_profiling_of_SARS-CoV-2_and_SARS-CoV_with_implications_for_clinical_manifestations_transmissibility_and_laboratory_studies_of_COVID-19_an_obser) shows minimal change in cell viability of HeLa cells innoculated with SARS-CoV and SARS-CoV2, but it's probably a good resource for how cell-culture infections are performed. [This paper](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanmic/article/PIIS2666-5247(20)30008-2/fulltext) claims that VeroE6 is the standard cell line for producing viral stocks of SARS CoV-2.

Best of luck with your proposal.